# Google Script adding multiple lines based on cell value or date ranges

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

pretty new at this stuff, but trying hard to keep learning. I'm looking for a possible script or solution to essentially take a row of data and duplicate it based on the value of a cell within the row.

As an example, see [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P-J34k0p6PZoJI-xS7wom49OmoWhTgS9hLcCOrTuWrc/edit?usp=sharing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you want to achieve your goal using Javascript which is not Google Apps Script, I think that you are required to use Sheets API. You can read the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/). And also you can see the Quickstart at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

Comment: Welcome. _take a row of date and duplicate it based on the value of a cell within the row._ This description is hard to follow. Would you please edit your question to describe your problem and reference the sheets (and relevant ranges) in your spreadsheet, and make it clear which sheet contains the data, which cell is the one to be evaluated, what is the evaluation, where is the duplication to be made, and what data is to be  duplicated. Would you also please indicate whether the spreadsheet contains an example of a successful outcome and if not, please add a sheet showing the desired outcome.

Comment: Echoing off @Tedinoz, you might be able to achieve your goal with native sheet functions. Advanced solutions with js might also be an option, depending on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

`=ArrayFormula(vlookup(transpose(split(query(rept(row(A2:A)&" ",F2:F),,9^9)," ")),ArrayFormula({row(A2:A),A2:G}),{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0))`

In this sample, the formula is in cell I2. The headers in Row 1 are added manually.

---

[image: Sample input and output]

Credit: [infoinspired.com](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/insert-duplicate-rows-in-google-sheets/)

Comment: Is this answer was helpful, then you might consider accepting it.